# Spring RESTful Web services returning 404 requested resource not available after being deployed in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat, servlets

I'm using spring 4.1.4.RELEASE version and tomcat 7. I wanted to build a sample REST API using spring framework. My web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"> 
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>  
<display-name>OrganizationMaster</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
<filter-name>cors</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.bargadss.CORS.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>cors</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My rest-servlet.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.bargadss.Controller" />
 <annotation-driven />
 <beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
 <beans:property name="viewClass"  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
 <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
 <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean>
 </beans:beans>
```

I do not want any JSP files since I just want to return string(JSON string) from controller. My controller looks something like this:

```
package com.bargadss.Controller;

import com.bargadss.Utility.Department;
import com.bargadss.Utility.DepartmentController;
import com.bargadss.Utility.UserController;
import com.bargadss.Utility.Users;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @author Arindam
 *
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/OrganizationMaster/")
public class SpringServiceController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/users/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public Response createNewUser(@RequestBody String inputObj) {

     if (inputObj == null || inputObj.isEmpty()) {
         System.out.println("Data Not Received");
         return Response.status(400).build();
     }
     /* Step 1: Handle Incoming Data (if any) */
     JSONObject inputJsonObj = null;
     System.out.println("Data Received:" + inputObj);
     JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
     try {
         inputJsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonparser.parse(inputObj);
     } catch (ParseException e) {
         System.out.println("Parse Exception-> Cannot Conver Data Received To JSON");
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     Users user_obj = null;
     UserController userCtrl_obj = new UserController();         
     try {
         /* Step 2: Create a New User From The Incoming DATA */
         long uid = (long) inputJsonObj.get("id");
         String eMail = (String) inputJsonObj.get("eMail");
         String name = (String) inputJsonObj.get("Name");
         String contactNumber = (String)inputJsonObj.get("primaryPhone");
         String contactNumber2 = (String)inputJsonObj.get("secondaryPhone");
         String address = (String) inputJsonObj.get("address");
         user_obj = new Users(uid, eMail, name, contactNumber, contactNumber2, address);
         boolean temp = userCtrl_obj.createNewUser(user_obj);
         if(!temp){
             System.out.println(" ERROR INSERTING NEW USER PROFILE IN DB ");
             return Response.status(400).build();
         }    
     }catch (Exception e1) {
        System.out.println("Exception Creating a New User");
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(400).build();
     }
     return Response.status(200).build();
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/users/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public Response listAllUsers() {
     UserController userCtrl_obj = new UserController();
     ArrayList<Users> arr = userCtrl_obj.listUsers();
     String json = new Gson().toJson(arr);
     return Response.status(200).entity(json).build();
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/users/", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
 public Response updateUsers(@RequestBody String inputObj) {
     if (inputObj == null || inputObj.isEmpty()) {
         System.out.println("Data Not Received");
         return Response.status(400).build();
     }
     /* Step 1: Handle Incoming Data (if any) */
     JSONObject inputJsonObj = null;
     System.out.println("Data Received:" + inputObj);
     JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
     try {
         inputJsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonparser.parse(inputObj);
     } catch (ParseException e) {
         System.out.println("Parse Exception-> Cannot Conver Data Received To JSON");
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     UserController userCtrl_obj  = new UserController();
     try{
         JSONArray userArray_json = (JSONArray) inputJsonObj.get("records");
         if(!userArray_json.isEmpty()){
             JSONParser parser3 = new JSONParser();
             ArrayList<Users> userArray = new ArrayList<Users>();
             Users user_obj = null;
             for(Object o : userArray_json){
                 JSONObject jsonObject3 = (JSONObject) parser3.parse(o.toString());
                 long uid = (long) jsonObject3.get("id");            
                 String eMail = (String) jsonObject3.get("eMail");
                 String name = (String) jsonObject3.get("Name");
                 String contactNumber = (String)jsonObject3.get("primaryPhone");
                 String contactNumber2 = (String)jsonObject3.get("secondaryPhone");
                 String address = (String) jsonObject3.get("address");                  
                 user_obj = new Users(uid, eMail, name, contactNumber, contactNumber2, address);
                 userArray.add(user_obj);
             }
             boolean temp = userCtrl_obj.updateUser(userArray);
             if(!temp){
                 System.out.println("ERROR UPDATING USER PROFILE FROM DB");
                 return Response.status(400).build();
             }
         }       
     }catch (Exception e1) {
            System.out.println("Exception Creating a New User");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return Response.status(400).build();
      }
     return Response.status(200).build();        
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/users/", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
 public Response removeUsers() {         
     UserController userCtrl_obj = new UserController();
     boolean temp = userCtrl_obj.removeUsers();
     if(!temp){
         System.out.println("ERROR DELETING USER PROFILE FROM DB");
         return Response.status(400).build();
     }   
     return Response.status(200).build();
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public Response listAnUser(@PathVariable("userId") int userId) {
     UserController userCtrl_obj = new UserController();
     String userObj_json = userCtrl_obj.listAnUser(userId);
     String json = new Gson().toJson(userObj_json);
     return Response.status(200).entity(json).build();
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
 public Response updateAnUser(@PathVariable("userId") int userId) {

     UserController userCtrl_obj  = new UserController();
     boolean temp = userCtrl_obj.updateAnUser(userId);
     if(!temp){
         System.out.println("ERROR UPDATING USER PROFILE IN DB");
         return Response.status(400).build(); 
     }
     return Response.status(200).build();        
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
 public Response removeAnUser(@PathVariable("userId") int userId) {      
     UserController userCtrl_obj = new UserController();
     boolean temp = userCtrl_obj.removeAnUser(userId);
     if(!temp){
         System.out.println("ERROR DELETING USER PROFILE FROM DB");
         return Response.status(400).build();
     }   
     return Response.status(200).build();
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/departments/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public Response createNewDepartment(@RequestBody String inputObj) {

     if (inputObj == null || inputObj.isEmpty()) {
         System.out.println("Data Not Received");
         return Response.status(400).build();
     }
     /* Step 1: Handle Incoming Data (if any) */
     JSONObject inputJsonObj = null;
     System.out.println("Data Received:" + inputObj);
     JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
     try {
         inputJsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonparser.parse(inputObj);
     } catch (ParseException e) {
         System.out.println("Parse Exception-> Cannot Convert Data Received To JSON");
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     Department dept_obj = null;
     DepartmentController deptCtrl_obj = new DepartmentController();         
     try {
         /* Step 2: Create a New Dept From The Incoming DATA */
         long deptid = (long) inputJsonObj.get("id");            
         String departmentName = (String) inputJsonObj.get("departmentName");            
         dept_obj = new Department(deptid, departmentName);
         boolean temp = deptCtrl_obj.createNewDepartment(dept_obj);
         if(!temp){
             System.out.println(" ERROR INSERTING NEW DEPARTMENT PROFILE IN DB ");
             return Response.status(400).build();
         }    
     }catch (Exception e1) {
        System.out.println("Exception Creating a New User");
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(400).build();
     }
     return Response.status(200).build();
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/departments/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public Response listAllDepartments() {
     DepartmentController deptCtrl_obj = new DepartmentController();
     ArrayList<Department> arr = deptCtrl_obj.listDepartments();
     String json = new Gson().toJson(arr);
     return Response.status(200).entity(json).build();
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/departments/", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
 public Response updateDepartments(@RequestBody String inputObj) {
     if (inputObj == null || inputObj.isEmpty()) {
         System.out.println("Data Not Received");
         return Response.status(400).build();
     }
     /* Step 1: Handle Incoming Data (if any) */
     JSONObject inputJsonObj = null;
     System.out.println("Data Received:" + inputObj);
     JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
     try {
         inputJsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonparser.parse(inputObj);
     } catch (ParseException e) {
         System.out.println("Parse Exception-> Cannot Conver Data Received To JSON");
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     DepartmentController deptCtrl_obj  = new DepartmentController();
     try{
         JSONArray deptArray_json = (JSONArray) inputJsonObj.get("records");
         if(!deptArray_json.isEmpty()){
             JSONParser parser3 = new JSONParser();
             ArrayList<Department> deptArray = new ArrayList<Department>();
             Department dept_obj = null;
             for(Object o : deptArray_json){
                 JSONObject jsonObject3 = (JSONObject) parser3.parse(o.toString());
                 long deptid = (long) jsonObject3.get("id");             
                 String departmentName = (String) jsonObject3.get("departmentName");                                
                 dept_obj = new Department(deptid, departmentName);
                 deptArray.add(dept_obj);
             }
             boolean temp = deptCtrl_obj.updateDepartments(deptArray);
             if(!temp){
                 System.out.println("ERROR UPDATING DEPARTMENT PROFILE FROM DB");
                 return Response.status(400).build();
             }
         }       
     }catch (Exception e1) {
            System.out.println("Exception Creating a New Department");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return Response.status(400).build();
      }
     return Response.status(200).build();        
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/departments/", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
 public Response removeDepartments() {       
     DepartmentController deptCtrl_obj  = new DepartmentController();
     boolean temp = deptCtrl_obj.removeDepartments();
     if(!temp){
         System.out.println("ERROR DELETING USER PROFILE FROM DB");
         return Response.status(400).build();
     }   
     return Response.status(200).build();
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/departments/{deptId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public Response listDept(@PathVariable("deptId") int deptId) {
     DepartmentController deptCtrl_obj  = new DepartmentController();
     String deptObj_json = deptCtrl_obj.listDept(deptId);
     String json = new Gson().toJson(deptObj_json);
     return Response.status(200).entity(json).build();
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/departments/{deptId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
 public Response updateDept(@PathVariable("deptId") int deptId) {        
     DepartmentController deptCtrl_obj  = new DepartmentController();
     boolean temp = deptCtrl_obj.updateDept(deptId);
     if(!temp){
         System.out.println("ERROR UPDATING USER PROFILE IN DB");
         return Response.status(400).build(); 
     }
     return Response.status(200).build();        
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/departments/{deptId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
 public Response removeDept(@PathVariable("deptId") int deptId) {        
     DepartmentController deptCtrl_obj  = new DepartmentController();
     boolean temp = deptCtrl_obj.removeDept(deptId);
     if(!temp){
         System.out.println("ERROR DELETING USER PROFILE FROM DB");
         return Response.status(400).build();
     }   
     return Response.status(200).build();
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/departments/{deptId}/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public Response createNewUserDept(@RequestBody String inputObj, @PathVariable("deptId") int deptId) {

     if (inputObj == null || inputObj.isEmpty()) {
         System.out.println("Data Not Received");
         return Response.status(400).build();
     }
     /* Step 1: Handle Incoming Data (if any) */
     JSONObject inputJsonObj = null;
     System.out.println("Data Received:" + inputObj);
     JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
     try {
         inputJsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonparser.parse(inputObj);
     } catch (ParseException e) {
         System.out.println("Parse Exception-> Cannot Convert Data Received To JSON");
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     Department dept_obj = null;
     DepartmentController deptCtrl_obj = new DepartmentController();         
     try {
         /* Step 2: Create a New Dept From The Incoming DATA */
         long deptid = (long) inputJsonObj.get("id");
         String departmentName = (String) inputJsonObj.get("departmentName");
         dept_obj = new Department(deptid, departmentName);
         boolean temp = deptCtrl_obj.createNewDepartment(dept_obj);
         if(!temp){
             System.out.println(" ERROR INSERTING NEW DEPARTMENT PROFILE IN DB ");
             return Response.status(400).build();
         }    
     }catch (Exception e1) {
        System.out.println("Exception Creating a New User");
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(400).build();
     }

     return Response.status(200).build();        
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/departments/{deptId}/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public Response listUsersByDept(@PathVariable("deptId") int deptId) {
     DepartmentController deptCtrl_obj  = new DepartmentController();
     String deptObj_json = deptCtrl_obj.listUsersByDept(deptId);
     String json = new Gson().toJson(deptObj_json);
     return Response.status(200).entity(json).build();
 }


}
```

I was able to successfully create a war file and deploy it on tomcat. But when I hit localhost:9999/OrganizationMaster/users/, I get 404. I'm using eclipse to build and deploy the package.

[image]

Comment: what context is your war deployed to? `localhost:9999/OrganizationMaster/users/` assumes the root context.

Comment: If you don't want any JSP files, you shouldn't have a `ViewResolver`, which maps responses from controller methods to `/WEB-INF/jsp/<thestring>.jsp`?

Comment: @Steve : Should I just remove The viewResolver from rest-servlet.xml, will that solve the entire Issue ?

Comment: Also, unless there's a specific exception that I'm not aware of, by annotating your controller as a `RestController`, Spring is going to try to convert it to JSON (i.e. it flags your response as `@ResponseBody`). Which I'm guessing might not be what you want, given that you already seem to have performed a JSON mapping.

Comment: @user2264997 Can you please elaborate your question ?

Comment: I'm not sure how Spring plays with JAX-RS, so I can't be sure whether that's sufficient. Is there a reason you're using it? You would save yourself a couple of lines per controller method if you just returned the resources instead of manually marshalling them.

Comment: I think I am very late but I could not find an answer to this question. Could you please try with localhost:9999/<webAppName>/OrganizationMaster/users/